# Front gear issues with middle ring (not always making it over)

Tags: gears, shifter, derailleur-front

I've been trying to straighten out some shifting issues on a kid's bike, it's a Diamondback and is a few years old. On the front gear-set it has a few issues that I am having trouble fixing through l and h screw adjustment and indexing.

- When shifting from the small ring to the middle it doesn't always make the shift, I have to twist it a little past the audible click to ensure a shift.
- Also it's shifting into the big ring way too early. When moving the shifter about halfway to the audible click it's already moved over, letting go at this point results in a downshift.

From what I'm interpreting fixing one of these issues would make the other worse. Does anyone have some tips?

Comment: The problem you describe sounds plausible for a lower end group-set on a kids bike. Is the faster shifting into the big ring really a problem? Can the shifter not be just moved until it clicks?

Comment: Having worked on a diamondback in the past, its pretty much the definition of cheap BSO.   Do you have gripshifters or driction thumb shifters or indexed shifters or pod shifters?

Comment: Also, your limit screw adjustment might be a bit early.  You want to get the shifter placing the chain right first, and then worry about limiting it's movement after that.   The initial adjust should be length of inner cable.

Comment: @Criggie Its got gripshifter's, and ill redo my limit screws and indexing.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus The shifting into the big ring is not the main issue, its the up-shift into the middle. I just wanted to provide all the info I could.

Comment: I've worked on 2 bikes with gripshifts and they've both been rubbish at shifting the front.  The *better* of the 2 bikes would get to stiff-but-workable with lots of tweaking, before deteriorating within a few rides to  the point where it only shifted after you'd given up trying to make it, but went over a pothole

Comment: are all the parts original? if you've replaced the cables/housing, checked and fiddled with F derailler angle (usually should be parallel with chainrings but sometimes a little angle helps) and double checked your limit screws, the issue may be a derailler that isn't compatible with your crankset.

Answer (score 1):

On the shifter handle, get the adjustment nut all the way in(where cable connects to the handle). Now get yourself some new brake outer and inner cable. Lube it very well, with oil(not grease, nor WD-40)

Now for derailleur, one screw is for the lower limit, the other one is for the upper limit. This is to ensure that the chain will not go out of the gears

Now shift into the lower gear, and fix the cable on the derailleur as tight as you can but without moving the derailleur. Once this is done you just need to use the adjustment nuts on the handle or the derailleur. I like adjusting it from the derailleur as the first fine tunning and any other from the handle, so I can keep track of how much wear the cables have.

Also check out if the derailleur is straight and parallel to the chain rings.  If it's not, it will not shift properly.

Comment: Personally I do it the other order - I get the chain shifting right and then  tweak the limit screws.  If the chain falls off while doing the first bit its no big deal because the transmission is not under load.

Comment: All modern brake cable is teflon lined and does not require lubing.  Adding a lubricant can have the opposite effect.

Comment: @Criggie Never had an issue using teflon lined sheats(pigtail and stright cable made) with lube. I've learned this from my local bike shop. Other technique is to set the lower limit a little bit to the center(so it won't go to the smaller ring) then set the cable, and set the lower limit back. But I do prefer to do the fine tune with the adjuting nuts.